# OpenMP parallel instantiation and modification of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, openmp, boost-geometry

I'm using OpenMP to parallelize some union operation on Boost::geometry polygons (`BPolygon`).
However I am stumbling over very strange exceptions that only occur from time to time (despite my RNGs being seeded with the same seed) so I wonder whether I'm ignoring some undefined behaviors with OpenMP parallelization and containers...

The code is part of a large and rather complex ensemble so I cannot really provide a MWE but the relevant parts are as follow:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<size_t, std::vector<std::vector<BPolygon>>> container;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    std::vector<BPolygon> vec_geom;

    #pragma omp for
    for (size_t gid : gids)
    {
        [...]
        auto iter_block, iter_block_end;

        container[gid] = std::vector<std::vector<BPolygon>>();

        while (iter_block != iter_block_end)
        {
            auto iter_node = neurite_it->second->nodes_cbegin();
            auto iter_node_end = neurite_it->second->nodes_cend();

            // store the union in vec_geom
            vec_geom.clear();

            while (iter_node != iter_node_end)
            {
                cascading_union(node_it->second, vec_geom);
                iter_node++;
            }

            // add the union to the container
            container[gid].push_back(vec_geom);

            iter_block++;
        }
    }
}
```

with the cascading union function being

```cpp
void cascading_union(TNodePtr n, std::vector<BPolygon> &vec_geom)
{
    auto range = n->segment_range();
    auto seg_it = range.begin();
    auto seg_end = range.end();

    std::vector<BPolygon> vec, vec_tmp;
    BPolygon poly1, poly2;

    // container associated to `range` cannot be modified so
    // we store the first unions in a new vector
    while (seg_it != seg_end)
    {
        poly1 = *((*seg_it).get());

        seg_it++;

        if (seg_it != seg_end)
        {
            poly2 = *((*seg_it).get());

            bg::union_(poly1, poly2, vec_tmp);

            vec.push_back(vec_tmp[0]);

            vec_tmp.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            vec.push_back(poly1);
        }
    }

    stype imax(vec.size()), imax2;

    // cascading union on final vector
    while (imax > 1)
    {
        imax2 = 0;

        for (stype i=0; i < imax; i += 2)
        {
            poly1 = vec[i];

            if (i + 1 < imax)
            {
                poly2 = vec[i + 1];

                bg::union_(poly1, poly2, vec_tmp);

                vec[imax2] = vec_tmp[0];

                vec_tmp.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                vec[imax2] = poly1;
            }

            imax2++;
        }

        vec.resize(imax2);
        imax = imax2;
    }

    if (imax > 0)
    {
        vec_geom.push_back(vec.back());
    }
}
```

The type of errors that are encounter are:

- in the first part of the code:

  - a segfault at allocation of `container[gid] = std::vector<std::vector<BPolygon>>();`
  - `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` (precise location unknown)
- in `cascading_union`:

- an segfault in `bg::union_`
- `free(): invalid next size (fast)` (precise location unknown)
- `malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected` (precise location unknown)

Please let me know if full backtraces would be useful.

I am wondering whether, though containers are supposed to be thread-safe, it could be an issue with the fact that here I'm dealing with variable size objects inside the container.

**Note:** these errors stem from a recent restructuring, so I think that there is no issue with the polygons or underlying structures because the errors were absent from previous implementations.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is not a thread-safe container in any way. When you're using `operator[]`, like `container[gid]`, if `gid` isn't in the the map already it will be added, with many threads working at the same time there can be a case where two or more threads try to reallocate the inner map structure at the same time, causing a crash.

Comment: You should also be careful with range for loops. Many of the earlier versions of openmp don't support them.

Comment: "_though containers are supposed to be thread-safe_" which containers, as stated where?

Comment: thanks, I don't know why I had this thought about containers being thread-safe, I probably remembered that access was safe and forgot it was access only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the comments, I realized that my idea about containers being thread-safe was wrong (well they are safe to read but not to modify).

Assignments and call to `push_back` must be wrapped in

```cpp
#pragma omp critical
```

Comment: Note that critical sections are costly. For good performance, you can create the vector `std::vector<std::vector<BPolygon>>()` locally and then `std::move` it in `container[gid]` at the end of each parallel for iteration. Even better: you can create a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<BPolygon>>>` of fixed-size `length(gids)`, move the values in parallel in the big vector and then converts the big vector in an `std::unordered_map` (and take care of `std::move` the values for sake of efficiency). This second approach should not require any critical sections and should be faster.

Comment: yes, I was planning to do something like your first part, however I'm not sure I understand the second: how do you move a vector to an unordered map?

Comment: I assume `gids` are values between 0 and N but it may not be the case. If not you can store the gid value too using a `std::vector<std::pair<size_t, ...>>`. For the move, you can just resize `container` and then do a sequential loop (after the parallel one) calling `container.emplace(std::move(item))` for each item (pair) in the big vector.

Comment: OK, I tried the second option and it does seem to give some marginal speed improvement compared to using the critical blocks but it seems that critical may not be that expensive anymore: improvements are on the order of 5%. That's always good to take though... so thank you :)

Comment: Another option is to use thread safe containers from Threading Building Blocks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks

Comment: thanks for the information, I did not know about it, but I'd rather not limit my program to Intel CPUs and there does not seem to be extensive ARM support in oneTBB